# Connect 12V 38A battery to SIM800C GSM Module

Tags: power, gsm, current, voltage

I have a gsm module that is rated for 12V and 1A. And I also have a drone Battery that is 12V and 38A. Would it hurt the gsm module If I connect it to this high power Battery?

I heard It's voltage that goes through forcefully, but current doesn't force it self through. So would it be safe to connect?

Comment: Your picture is of a HP server power supply. What does it have to do with the question?

Comment: @StarCat IT'S HAS THE SAME OUTPUT, WHAT'S THE DIFFERENCE?

Comment: The difference is: One is a battery, the other is a mains connected power supply. Do you have a datasheet of your battery? Are you sure your battery is 38A and not 38Ah? Because that would be much more useful information than a picture of a random power supply that has nothing to do with your question. Anyway, you can connect your battery and all will be fine (probably) because your SIM module will only use the current it needs.

Comment: @StarCat It's Turnigy LiPo pack with current upto 38A
https://youtu.be/EYkd6c6Gqyg?t=308

Comment: I really don’t want to watch a Youtube video, but it will probably do the job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When choosing a battery there are three basic parameters that need to be considered:

1. Voltage
2. Capacity
3. Max. current draw

In your case you have listed the requirement as 12V 1A which means you need 12V and the maximum current need is 1 Amp.  You have said nothing about capacity, which is how much energy is stored in the battery so I assume it's not important here.

Your proposed 12V 38A battery will work just fine since it's still 12V and the 38A is simply the maximum current draw, not the minimum.  The battery will provide up to 38A but will also source less.

Be careful, though.  If you create an accidental short circuit there is a large amount of energy stored in a 38A type battery and it will be discharged very quickly indeed, possibly causing a fire.  Be sure to properly insulate your wires and connections.

Answer (score 0):

I looked up the SIM800C GSM Module, and it seems it requires a Lithium Ion or Lithium polymer battery, and has a built-in charging circuit in it. (It sounds like it uses the battery to manage peak current demands.) Thus you MUST use a rechargeable lithium battery for it. Having a higher current battery should be fine as long as the voltage is correct.